# Hide apiKey in JS and JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have several fragments of code in which I have written my Google's api key or clientId such as:

```
<ffu:ffuAttachDocumentFromDriveBS
        apikey="MY_API_KEY"
        clientId="MY_CLIENT_ID"
        fileId="#{documentManagerBean.fileId}"
        downloadMethod="#{documentManagerBean.downloadFileAndUploadToBeeblos()}"
        render="attachment_message, #{id_mpAttachment}_doc"/>
```

or

```
_doAuth: function(immediate, callback) {    
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        immediate: immediate
    }, callback);
}
```

so if anyone were to inspect the code in the browser, they would see them.

Is there any way to hide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Google API Key must be placed in your HTML or JS files. So, yes, everyone **can look**.

But remeber that *Google generate the API key for a specific domain*.
So, **a stolen key, can not be used**.

The problem is that some developers, *does not attach the API key to their domains properly*, Google **recommends** **attach to specific domain** to prevent bad usages.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a Browser key and Server key. The browser key is okay to use on the browser. Your server key is the one you don't want exposed. You can use Cloud Functions or AWS Lambda to do your server side API calls.